# HTML forms that needs to save data with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, post

I'm trying to make a form whose fields will be automatically populated from the url. Also, if user clicks on "Save me a seat" it should redirect to one location, send email and save cookies. If user clicks on "Not interested, thank you", it should redirect him/her to another location, send email and save cookies.

Now, I haven't worked with PHP for 2 years now and there is much that I forgot.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
// Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$title = $_POST['positiontitle'];
$company = $_POST['companyname'];
$all = array($firstname, $lastname, $title, $company);
if($firstname !=''&& $lastname !=''&& $title !=''&& $company !='')
{
//  To redirect form on a particular page
header("Location:http://www.example.com");
}
else{
?><span><?php echo "Please fill in all fields!";?></span> <?php
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta content="noindex, nofollow" />
</head>
<body>
 <form class="conf-form" method="POST">
    <legend>Please input your information:</legend><br />
    First name:<br>
    <input class="fst-name" type="text" name="firstname" value="First Name">
    <br><br />
    Last name:<br>
    <input class="lst-name" type="text" name="lastname" value="Last Name">
    <br /><br />
    Position title:<br />
    <input class"pos-title" type="text" name="positiontitle" value="Position Title"/>
    <br /> <br />
    Company name:<br />
    <input class="cmp-name" type="text" name="companyname" value="Company Name"/>
    <br /><br />
    <input id="save-me" type="submit" value="Save me a seat" name="submit">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="not-int" type="submit" value="Not interested, thank you" name="notsubmit">
    <br /><br />
    If you have any comments/questions please let us know here:<br />
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

It's not redirecting where I want it. For start, how do I fix this?

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: I have made edits. :)Sorry

Comment: Should we assume that the PHP Code you quote is in `includes/redirect.php` and therefore included at the bottom of the HTML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirecting cannot be made after you have already sent content. In your case, you have already have HTML content before running [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

This *should* trigger an error but you probably have error reporting turned off. To turn on error reporting, you'll need to include this at the top of your main PHP file that runs every time:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This will save you time when developing.

To solve your exact problem, you need to move the PHP include file above your HTML content.

Comment: If you remember the Life Cycle of a web page, PHP code should almost always be at the top of a file and include a test so it only runs if some action (pressed a button) has taken place.

Comment: What do you mean 'nothing happens'? You know that does not help. Have you moved all of your PHP above HTML? Have you turned on error reporting?

Comment: Sorry, I was in a rush. Apologies. Please see the edited question.

Comment: Yeah, move the PHP to the **top** of the file. It should be above **everything**. This includes `html` and `doctype` and `head`. Also, move the error reporting code above all other PHP code.

Comment: I did. Now when I click on "submit", I only get this path:

http://localhost/form.php?firstname=First+Namedsadas&lastname=Last+Namedsadas&positiontitle=Position+Titledsadas&companyname=Company+ddds&submit=Save+me+a+seat

Comment: Okay, so you're actually sending the form using *GET* instead of *POST*. Add `method="POST"` in your form element. Also, update your code to show that you have moved all your PHP above all the HTML.

Comment: Yeah, I completely forgot about the method="POST". It's redirecting now as it should. But what I need is when user clicks on "Save me a seat" the form redirects him to for example page1.php. If the user clicks on "not interested, thank you" the form redirects him to the page1.php

Comment: You said *page1.php* twice but that's probably a mistype. You should have no problem using `header('/page1.php')` to redirect him where you want to. You can always check which submit button was clicked by checking if `$_POST['submit']` or `$_POST['notsubmit']` [is set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Comment: Yeah, I it was a mistype. Also, as the users will some to this signup page via email. How do I populate some fields, for example "first name" and "last name" with their information automatically?

Comment: You'll have to provide them with a link like *http://url.com?name=test&last=toast* Then you can check if a `$_GET['name']` and/or `$_GET['last']` exist and  then put them inside the *value* of the inputs.

Comment: So basically in the input fields I use method="GET" for the fields that I want to be populated?

Comment: No. You use something like `<?php echo if(isset($_GET['name'])) ? $_GET['name'] : '' ?>` inside the input's *value* parameter. Anyways, it is a totally different question and requires a new question but it should be googlable pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code is not getting run. The default method for a `form` is `get`, in your code you try to take something from a `HTTP POST` which never gets send.

To solve that you should either change the form `method` attribute, or change your PHP to use `$_GET`. I would recommend to add `method='post'` to your form tag. For more information take a look at these two pages on PHP.net, [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) and [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

For what you describe in your question

> I'm trying to make a form whose fields will be automatically populated from the url.

Maybe the `get` would be more interesting for you.

Next to that, why have this code:

```
If you have any comments/questions please let us know here:<br />
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

If you are not using it anyway. If you are going to use it, then you should use `post` as your form method, seeing that a url (and so `get`) has a limit on its size. Either way you might want to add a `name` attribute to this textarea.

To recap

1. Change your `form method` to `post`, or change your PHP code to `$_GET`
2. Add a `name` attribute to your `textarea` so that it will be accessable by your code and not useless